# You can't use `\prevdepth' in restricted horizontal mode

Tags: tables

I've had some troubles typesetting a table. At first, the table wasn't being centering despite my code. And then when I used the adjustbox command to resize the table Latex gave me the following error:

You can't use `\prevdepth' in restricted horizontal mode.

Here is the code

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width = \textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Changes in Wage Inequality and Institutions}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1980--1990} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1990--2000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2000--2010} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2010--2015} \\ \midrule
Wage Inequality       &     $\underset{(6.0)}{12.4}$      &  $\underset{(7.3)}{8.7}$    & $\underset{(3.5)}{4.0}$     &    $\underset{(3.3)}{4.3}$       \\
Manufacturing         &        $\underset{(3.3)}{-4.0}$      & $\underset{(2.1)}{-2.8}$   &  $\underset{(2.0)}{-3.0}$  & $\underset{(0.8)}{-0.5}$    \\
Union Membership      &    $\underset{(5.0)}{-9.8}$  &  $\underset{(3.9)}{-2.3}$       & $\underset{(5.0)}{-0.01}$   & $\underset{(5.4)}{-0.8}$          \\
Managerial Employment &   $\underset{(22.2)}{34.5}$      & $\underset{(22.1)}{31.7}$   & $\underset{(25.6)}{23.9}$   & $\underset{(8.5)}{-0.5} $       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize{\item{Samples include persons between the ages of 18 and 65 years old, currently employed and worked in the prior year.  Wage inequality is measured here as the log variance of real weekly earnings of all non-self-employed  workers. Changes in manufacturing and union employment are changes in their respective employment shares. Changes in managerial and supervisory employment are measured as the growth in managerial and supervisory employment of the private, non-farm labor force. All rates are multiplied by 100. Standard deviations are reported beneath in parentheses. \\
\emph{Source}: Census 5 percent samples for 1980, 1990, and 2000. American Community Survey 5-year Estimates 2010 and 2015.}}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

And the packages from my preamble

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

Comment: I didn't check the error about `\prevdepth` but if you want your table to be centered, just remove the `flushleft` option when you load the `threeparttable` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. ! Please put your preamble and your table in one single MWE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simple: you can't have a `threeparttable` environment inside `adjustbox`.

Scaling a table should be the very last resort. In this case you don't even need `threeparttable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\data}[2]{$\underset{(#1)}{#2}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Changes in Wage Inequality and Institutions}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccc@{}}
\toprule
   & 1980--1990 & 1990--2000 & 2000--2010 & 2010--2015 \\
\midrule
Wage Inequality       &
  \data{6.0}{12.4}  & \data{7.3}{8.7}   & \data{3.5}{4.0}   & \data{3.3}{4.3} \\
Manufacturing         &
  \data{3.3}{-4.0}  & \data{2.1}{-2.8}  & \data{2.0}{-3.0}  & \data{0.8}{-0.5} \\
Union Membership      &
  \data{5.0}{-9.8}  & \data{3.9}{-2.3}  & \data{5.0}{-0.01} & \data{5.4}{-0.8} \\
Managerial Employment &
  \data{22.2}{34.5} & \data{22.1}{31.7} & \data{25.6}{23.9} & \data{8.5}{-0.5} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip

\footnotesize
Samples include persons between the ages of 18 and 65 years old, 
currently employed and worked in the prior year.  Wage inequality is 
measured here as the log variance of real weekly earnings of all
non-self-employed  workers. Changes in manufacturing and union
employment are changes in their respective employment shares.
Changes in managerial and supervisory employment are measured
as the growth in managerial and supervisory employment of the
private, non-farm labor force. All rates are multiplied by 100.
Standard deviations are reported beneath in parentheses.

\emph{Source}: Census 5 percent samples for 1980, 1990, and 2000.
American Community Survey 5-year Estimates 2010 and 2015.

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *could* use `threeparttable` inside `adjustbox`, provided you add a `minipage`; but this is the output you get with your code after adding `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` before `\begin{threeparttable}` and `\end{minipage}` after `\end{threeparttable}`

[image]

You can notice the wrong space before the note text.